# to prove that $F(c)=3c^2$

Tags: definite-integrals

F(x) is a continuous function on [0,1], Such that 
$ \int_0^1 F(t)\,dt$=1. Prove that there exists a number c $\in$ (0,1) such that F(c)=3$c^2$.

Comment: How are $f$ and $F$ related? Are they supposed to be the same function? What are your thoughts and efforts on the problem so far?

Comment: ya ya.. sry . they are same!!

Comment: Got something from the answer below?

Answer (score 3):

Otherwise, by the IVT, either $F(x)\gt3x^2$ for every $x$ in $(0,1]$, or $F(x)\lt3x^2$ for every $x$ in $(0,1]$. Since $\int\limits_0^13x^2\mathrm dx=1$, in both cases, $\int\limits_0^1F(x)\mathrm dx\ne1$, which is absurd.